Hierarchical select modules are showing excessive widgets during entity editing
For a few months now I noticed some difficulty editing entities using either 'simple hierarchical select' formatter or the 'client side hierarchical select' formatter. The widget splits up offering multiple widgets at the end, as shown in the image below.
 This is a single taxonomy reference field with terms Nigeria > Lagos > Surulere but now it gets split up as though they were multiple fields.
If you edit the entity (with 'Force the deepest level selection' turned on) and try to safe with the loads of widgets you will get errors as shown in the images below. You can only save after removing the duplicate widgets.


If you edit the entity (with 'Force the deepest level selection' turned off) you will be able to save but equally you will be able to save multiple locations e.g. Nigeria can be saved twice with different states and Germany, United States > New York, etc can also be allowed to save on the same field.
